# How to redirect base url to html

Tags: windows, tomcat

I use Windows server and apache tomcat. My application is deployed on root folder. So, if you want open my app you must send reqeust to checkerweb.tk/main.html.
What is the best way to redirect checkerweb.tk to checkerweb.tk/main.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: In your `WEB-INF/web.xml` just add this fragment in the appropriate place

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>main.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```